# product of the power series expansion of geometric and exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

I know the power series expansion around the point $0$ for $\frac{1}{1-t}$ and $\exp(t)$ for $|t| < 1$. Now let $u \in \mathbb{R}$ and define

$$
f(t) := \frac{1}{1-t} \exp\left\{ \frac{-ut}{1-t} \right\}.
$$
What is the power series expansion of $f$ around $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a closed-form expression for the coefficients, but they satisfy the recurrence
$$ (n+1) a_n+(u-3-2n)a_{n+1}+(n+2) a_{n+2} = 0 $$
with $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 1-u$.  This comes from the differential equation
$$ (t-1)^2 y' + (u+t-1) y = 0 $$
satisfied by $f$.

Comment: The solution is given by $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}L_{n}(u)t^{n}$ where $L_{m}(u) = \sum_{k=0}^{m}(-1)^{k}{m \choose k}u^{k} / k!$ are the Laguerre Polynomials. I don't see, how to came to this solution

Comment: Ah!  The Laguerre polynomials do indeed have this generating function and recurrence relation.